# can i "freeze the code" of activescaffold or rails_admin in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activescaffold

i want to generate a complex scaffold and then remove the gems 
is there a way to freeze the code that rails_admin or activescaffold generates so i can edit it myself ? (similar to how rails scaffold does it)
is there another gem that generates a more complex scaffold?

Answer (score 0):

In active scaffold to alter a scaffold's views you use [overrides](https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold/wiki/_pages).

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what version of Rails you're running.  If >2.1, you can specify gems explicitly in environment.rb using `config.gem`, and then run `rake gems:unpack` to freeze those gems into the vendor/gems folder.  For >=3.0 use the Builder tool to freeze the gem.

If <= 2.1, then you could do the above step manually -- copy all of the ActiveScaffold gem code into a folder in vendor/plugins, and remove the gem itself.  See earlier plugin-based versions of ActiveScaffold for guidance.

You can also do this only as needed.  To customize views, create an app/views/active_scaffold_overrides folder, and copy any ActiveScaffold partials to customize there.  They will automatically be used across your app -- no need to duplicate them into each view.  To customize controller actions, create a controller named ActiveScaffold, and then have all other scaffold controllers inherit from this new `ActiveScaffoldController`.  Now you have somewhere to override the actions themselves, and you can override helpers in the generated `ActiveScaffoldHelper` file too.